# React state hook with an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const App = () => {
  const [User, setUser] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: "ed",
    age: Number,
    edit: false
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={User.name} onChange={e => setUser.name(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am working with react hooks. I set the initial state to an object. I try changing the value with react hooks but this gives an error `TypeError: setUser.name is not a function`

Comment: `setUser` is function and not object that's what you trying do. just change it to
`<input value={User.name} onChange={e => setUser((prevState) => {  ...prevState, name : e.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets look at the value of User and setUser

```js
const [User, setUser] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: "ed",
    age: Number,
    edit: false
  });
```

`React.useState` returns a value and a setter to that value. `setUser` is a function. So while User.name is a string with the initial value of "ed" setUser.name doesn't exist. The error `TypeError: setUser.name is not a function` is the result of trying to pass an undefined value an argument. One way of solving this is as Murtaza Hussain and other answers suggest:

```
  <input 
    value={User.name}
    onChange={e => setUser(prev => ({...prev, name: e.target.value}))}
  />
```

As an alternative you can use a custom `useObjState` hook, which provides a rather simple API.

### UseObjState hook

```js
const useObjState = initialObj => {
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState(initialObj);
  const setObjHelper = useMemo( () => { // the value of setObjHelper is permanent, so even if it is passed to a child component, it shouldn't require extra component updates
    const helper = {}
    Object.keys(initialObj).forEach(key => {
      helper[key] = newVal => setObj({ ...obj, [key]: newVal });
    });
    return helper
  }, [])
  return [obj, setObjHelper];
};
```

It provides a much easier/cleaner way to update the value of the name property.

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useObjState({
    id: 1,
    name: "ed",
    age: Number,
    edit: false
  });

  return (
    <input 
      value={user.name} 
      onChange={e => setUser.name(e.target.value)} />
    />
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/small-worker-titb1)

Comment: Hi Ben, this does not answer the initial question, it suggests an alternative. I would put this as a comment and not an answer as someone might flag or downvote. Just my opinion. It's a great suggestion, but not an answer to the question as to why he is getting an error on the code he wrote specifically.

Comment: @EricBishard, Thanks for your comment. I agree. I made some adjustments to better answer the question. Please take a look, and let me know if you still think there is an issue.

Answer (score 9):

`setUser` is a function which you use to update the state and since it just replaces the state you need to merge your previous state value too. Also event is cleared in callback so you need to get the value before using the callback of setUser. Its better to write a handler function for this. Also you can write a generic function to handle setting all values

```js
const App = () => {
      const [User, setUser] = React.useState({
        id: 1,
        name: "ed",
        age: Number,
        edit: false
      }); 
      const handleChange = (e) => {
         const {value, name} = e.target;
         setUser(prev => ({...prev, [name]: val}))
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <input value={User.name} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: Getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @Navish Did you create the handler as I suggested, you have to read the value before the state updater callback otherwise it will be cleared

Answer (score 2):

`setUser` is a function same as `setState`.. for more details check [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
  <input 
    value={User.name}
    onChange={e => setUser(prev => ({...prev, name: e.target.value}))}
  />
```

in your context:

```
const App = () => {
  const [User, setUser] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: "ed",
    age: Number,
    edit: false
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        value={User.name}
        onChange={e => setUser(prev => ({...prev, name: e.target.value}))}
      />
  );
};
```